# Text over background colored getting a weird yellow border

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, cmyk, color-conversion, color-profile

I'm working on a logo using illustrator. I just put a black text over a red shape and my text is getting a boring yellow border around it. In this case, shape is red, but whatever the color I use, same issue happens. See below:

[image]

Note that there is a yellow edge around text. Why is that happening? My doc is on CMYK with the profile FOGRA39, but I noticed same issue when using default Working CMYK too.

Comment: Looks like you have rasterized text or you have forgotten View > Pixel Preview=ON. In both cases the edge antialiasing makes edges half transparent to reduce jagginess.

Comment: Actually, I followed the Billy Kerr tip and set transparency mode to "multiply". I don't know why adobe does that.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's caused by anti-aliasing, used by Illustrator to display graphics without pixelated edges. However, anti-aliasing causes display artefacts when two colours butt up against each other. The problem doesn't only affect Illustrator, but also other similar vector image editors.

You can eliminate the problem by selecting the text box, open the Appearance panel, and click on *Opacity* and set it to *Multiply* mode.

Example before (left) and after (right)

[image]

Alternatively, if this is for a print job, you can simply ignore it, since it's not really there. It will only affect what's displayed on screen.

Comment: Thanks for answering! It worked, but actually in the past I already sent a business card to print, one of its sides had a black background, and it was delivered to me with that same yellow border around all text over black. I complained to the print shop, they accepted and sent me another box of 500 cards, and they got, again, the same problem. Since then, I don't make any art with a black background. I posted my doubt on lots of forums, no one could gimme a solution.

Comment: @joaogdesigner - I think that may be another problem. There's no way to tell for sure without examining the print however, but I suspect possible misregistration. Do you have a printers loupe, linen tester, or magnifying glass to examine it closely? [Trapping](https://printhouse.co.uk/2010/01/what-is-trapping-and-how-is-it-used-in-print/) can eliminate such misregistration problems in print.

Comment: I don't have that. The print shop actually was one of those who get orders from an online store and customers can't go in person to give details about how the work must be printed as they an online-based print shop. That was about 10 years ago, but nowadays I still avoid creating art over black backgrounds or even dark backgrounds, unless the client liked that idea and wants to pay for. Over white is easier :)